# F# async lambda declaration

Tags: ios, asynchronous, f#, xamarin

In C# Xamarin iOS I can do this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread( () => { //do stuff here});
```

where the argument for InvokeOnMainThread is NSAction

In F# I have to do

```
InvokeOnMainThread (new NSAction(fun _ -> //do stuff here))
```

But in C# i can also do

```
InvokeOnMainThread (async () => { //do stuff here});
```

how would I do the same in F#?

---

Also, in my case, in C# i do this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(async() => { await Task.Delay(1100); });
```

how can i express the same thing in F#?

Comment: `InvokeOnMainThread (async () => { /* do stuff here */ })` If I read [the docs](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction%29) correctly, this will create an `async void` method from the lambda. That's mot likely not what you want (try throwing an exception after the delay).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have Xamarin installed to actually try this, but I think the following should do the trick:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(NSAction(fun _ -> 
   async { do! Async.Sleep(1000)
           (* some more stuff *) }
   |> Async.StartImmediate
))
```

I'm a bit puzzled why you need to specify the `NSAction` delegate type, but I guess there might be some overloading issue with it, so perhaps it is actually needed.

The example above creates an ordinary lambda function that creates an async block inside the body of the function and then immediately starts it on the current thread. This is a reasonable choice here, because you are starting with sleep - but if you were doing some CPU-intensive work, it would be better to start the async in the background using `Async.Start`.

Comment: Thanks!  actually, i should probably have read more examples on github before asking the previous question.  instead of declaring new NSAction and using fun _ -> you can just say InvokeOnMainThread(fun() -> ... )  perhaps all just a learning process!